# Javafx Get Image Date Information

Tags: java, date, javafx, javafx-8, exif

I am using javaFX wish to retrieve the information of image like Date, size, format etc. Below is the partial code which i use to retrieve the Image date.

I am able to retrieve the date information from the image file, but i am getting an issue.

1. The code will definitely run into [catch (Exception e)] part if i did not edit the image date previously.
2. if i did edit the date like the example below, then the code will work without go into [catch (Exception e)].

I cant't figure out what is the reason cause this to happen.
Please give some suggestion to fix the code bug or any logic issue within the code? Thanks in advance =)

[Image date Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLy6u.png)

[Image date Edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6VeZ.png)

```
Date date = null;
            try { 
            File imagefile = new File(Path);
            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(imagefile);
            ExifSubIFDDirectory directory = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class);
                if (directory!=null) {
                    // Read the date

                date = directory.getDate( ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL );
                DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
                df.format( date );
                int year = df.getCalendar().get( Calendar.YEAR );
                int month = df.getCalendar().get( Calendar.MONTH ) + 1;
                int day = df.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                System.out.println( "Year: " + year + ", Month: " + month );
                System.out.println("Day:"+day);

                System.out.println( "Date: " + date );                   
                    } else {
                        System.out.println( "EXIF is null" );
                    }    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Date Format cannot read exception");
            }
```

Comment: Please share the exception details and it will help to identify root cause

Comment: hi @HarisudanKuppusami , it run perfectly by just printing "Date Format cannot read exception" without causing any error, meaning it did not run the code of [ if ... else ]

Comment: In Exception trace, it will printout the line no and method details. Please share the entire exception detail

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing. Some misconceptions of the use of `DateFormat`? The method `format` takes a `Date` object and converts it to a string representation. The method `getCalendar` might get the object used previously but I am not sure of it. Instead of using `DateFormat` I would use `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.setTime(date); int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); ... `.

Comment: Hi. I tried on a bunch of images and found two possible problems. One is the files themselves beeing in a unreadable format. They are images but the format is nor readable by the metadata reader. An exception `com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException: File format is not supported` is thrown and there is nothing to be done about it. Another problem is when the date is not set. Then the `getDate` method returns null and you should test the date for null and give a message 'Date is null'.